# How to change document title from a child?

Tags: javascript, html

It's setup like this:

Parent.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Component Documentation</title>
</head>
<frame src="html\child.html" name="child">
</html>
```

Child.html

```
<select name="componentselect" size="24">
```

When the select box is clicked I need the Parent's title to change. Basically, I want the browser to display the item selected in "componentselect" to appear in the title bar. Setting the document.title in the Child.html isn't working.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using frames. They're deprecated.

Comment: Use: `top.document.title = "My desired title"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
function onSelectChange () {
  top.document.title = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

HTML

```
<select name="componentselect" onchange="onSelectChange()" size="24">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the `top.` or `parent.` prefix. It is like your `window.` prefix. `parent.` will point to the parent's `window` object. `top.` will point to the main website (in case of using multiple levels of frames). But in some browsers this feature is disabled or limited due to lack of security.

So this will work:

```
parent.document.title = "I came from outerspace!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do this 
Javascript function :

```
<script>

    function changeSelect()
    {
        parent.document.title = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    }
</script>
```

And the html :

```
<select name="componentselect" onchange="changeSelect()" size="24">
```

try parent or top, don't remember wich to use

Answer (score 0):

i recommend a Jquery solution, but that won't work from a frame, you might want to consider using divs, there's almost always an alternative to using frames (it might just require more code). Anyway here's the script that works for sure on a self contained html :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('#componentselect').click(function() {
    $(document).attr(’title’, $('#componentselect').val());
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: for using this, you'll need to set the id attribute to the same as name attribute.